# Do I have to update my css &/or js files if I break a jsp page into head,content,footer sections using Apache tiles3?

Tags: css, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

So my story is the following:

I downloaded a website template (bootstrap/html), ran it on my browser and everything works fine all responsive features and everything.

I imported this into my eclipse webapp converted it to JSP and ran it, also everything fine up till here.

Now what I did, I broke my pages into chunks (WITHOUT CHANGING ANYTHING IN THE TEMPLATE OR ADDING EXTRA SCRIPTS, SIMPLE SPLITTING) and converted it into Apache tiles3 structure (header/content/footer)

NOW I ran that, CSS works fine all pages and footer and the navigation bar/toggle, however noticed for example that the home button is always highlighted in addition to the current tab being viewed.
Another thing I noticed which really took a lot of debugging more time than I anticipated, there is a page with a portfolio clickable gallery with hover functionally (slides down expand button), all of this is working except the size of the box is expanding once I hover over it. it expands down and stays like that. not sure why this happened.
Below is the body of the defaultLayout.xml. Node that the header,body and footer each where originally their own section in the original template.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />

        <!-- script tags
    ============================================================= -->
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.mixitup.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
```

I already tried the following:

1. Made sure that I did not break any div elements when splitting header/content/footer.
2. Debugged it in my browser and made sure that all js ad css files loading fine.
3. Tried to remove some js or css files thinking maybe it is loading but not working see if I can spot it, but removing a single css or js file drastically changes the view.

Now I am tied not sure what do, it seems to me like css is dependent on the fact that the whole body is in the same file? or is it tiles:insertAttribute doing something that is causing this? If any one came across this before or have any thoughts, its greatly appreciated thanks. Hope I was clear enough.

Here is an image before converting to apache tiles structure 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x4H3.jpg)

Here is image after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow18f.jpg)

Thanks for your time. 
Here is my tiles.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layouts/defaultLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/template/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/template/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="SSELMAN" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="about" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="About" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/about.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="experience" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Experience" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/experience.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="works" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/works.jsp">

    </definition>
    <definition name="contact" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: can you show your tiles.xml config?

Comment: note definition **experience** and **works** are the same, works is the one that works (because all are in the same page; its a test) and **experience** the one with the issue. Added code to post.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but using jsp:include does not cause same issue as using apache tiles